# issue with mysql left join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

It's a continuation of my previous question.My first issue has been solved and got second one.

I have 2 tables

table_one (toneid is autoincrement with primary key)

```
  toneid   id       email
  1        634      45
  2        643      23
  3        648      55
```

table_two (tid is autoincrement with primary key)

```
tid
633
634
643
648
```

My desired result should be

```
tid      email
633      null
634      45
643      23
648      55
```

My query is

```
select table_two.tid, 
       table_one.id, 
       table_one.email 
from  table_two 
       left join table_one on table_one.id = table_two.tid
```

But it is returning

```
tid      email    
634      45
643      23
648      55
```

Comment: perhaps you are not looking for a left join but maybe a right outter join..

Comment: You need an outer join as what record in table_one gives one for tie =633

Comment: Is that really your full query?  the behavior you are seeing would be expected if you had a `WHERE` clause referencing table1, for example.  See this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fd169/1

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebdf7/1

Comment: yes Michael I have a where clause which I have to use.

Comment: If you've got a restricting condition on table_one, you've got to include this condition in the `ON` clause. Using such a condition in the `WHERE` clause changes your `OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.